# Linked List of Pointers that Point to Nodes in Another List

Tags: c++, list, pointers, linked-list

I am reading in a text file and organizing it for searching in C++.  We have to create an array of the keywords and a linked list of the WebPages in the text file.  Then we need to link the keywords to the webpages by each keyword having a linked list of pointers to the nodes themselves.  The keyword array needs to be in alphabetical order and the order of the web page list does not matter.  It seems list for each keyword is not working properly.

This is the keyword class:

```
class KeywordList
{
private:
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const KeywordList&);
public:
    struct Keyword
{
    std::string word;
    std::list<WebPageList::WebPage*> list;
};
Keyword keywords [1000];
std::size_t size;

KeywordList()
{
    size = 0;
}
~KeywordList() {}

void add(std::string value, WebPageList::WebPage* page)
{
    bool keepGoing = true;
    int i = 0;
    while (keepGoing)
    {
        if (value == keywords[i].word)
        {
            keywords[i].list.push_front(page);
            keepGoing = false;
        } else if (i == size) 
        {
            keywords[i].word = value;
            keywords[i].list.push_front(page);
            keepGoing = false;
            ++size;
        } else if (value < keywords[i].word) 
        {
            for (int j = size; j > i; --j)
            {
                keywords[j].word = keywords[j - 1].word;
                keywords[j].list = keywords[j - 1].list;
            }
            keywords[i].word = value;
            keywords[i].list.push_front(page);
            keepGoing = false;
            ++size;
        } else {
            ++i;
        }

    }
}

void search(std::string);

void printAllData()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << keywords[i].word << " : " << keywords[i].list.size() << " : ";
        WebPageList::WebPage * pagesList = keywords[i].list.front();
        while (pagesList)
        {
            std::cout << pagesList->url << " ";
            pagesList = pagesList->next;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

This is the webpage linked list:

```
    class WebPageList
{

public:

struct WebPage
{
    std::string url;
    WebPage * next;
};

WebPage * head;

WebPageList()
{
    head = NULL;
}

void add(std::string value)
{
    WebPage * newPage;
    newPage = new WebPage;
    newPage->url = value;

    if (!head)
    {
        head = newPage;
        newPage->next = NULL;
    }
    else 
    {
        newPage->next = head;
        head = newPage;
    }
}

void printAllPages()
{
    WebPage * page = head;
    while (page)
    {
        std::cout << page->url << std::endl;
        page = page->next;
    }
}
```

And this is the main:

```
ifstream dataFile;
    dataFile.open(argv[1], std::ios::in);

    KeywordList keywordList;
    WebPageList mainPages;

    int i = 0;
    std::string line;
    while (getline(dataFile, line))
    {
        std::string keyword, url;
        std::istringstream lineStream(line);
        lineStream >> url;
        mainPages.add(url);
        WebPageList::WebPage * passingPage = mainPages.head;

        while (lineStream >> keyword)
        {
            keywordList.add(keyword, passingPage);
            cout << endl;
            keywordList.printAllData();
        }
    }

    mainPages.printAllPages();

    dataFile.close();
```

Here is the output I get:

```
structures : 1 : http://test1 


structures : 1 : http://test1  
zzz : 1 : http://something http://test1



structures : 1 : http://test1  
zalgorithms : 2 : http://www.algorithms.com/ http://something http://test1  
zzz : 1 : http://something http://test1 


structures : 1 : http://test1  
zalgorithms : 2 : http://www.algorithms.com/ http://something http://test1  
zzz : 2 : http://somethingelse http://www.algorithms.com/ http://something http://test1 

http://somethingelse 
http://www.algorithms.com/ 
http://something 
http://test1
```

And it is based on this input file:

```
http://test1 structures 
http://something zzz 
http://www.algorithms.com/ zalgorithms  
http://somethingelse zzz
```

I am at a huge loss so any help would really be appreciated!